# Websockets through URLSessionWebSocketTask

Tags: swift, websocket, watchos, urlsession

I'm currently having some trouble using the new URLSessionWebSocketTask in my WatchOS 6 application. The server side requires me to first send the authentication data through HTTP-headers before the websocket can be established. Since URLSessionWebSocketTask contains a function that takes an URLRequest as an argument, my approach is the following:

```
 func establishSocket(){

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://censored.url”)!)

    urlRequest.addValue("applicationtype”, forHTTPHeaderField: “ApplicationType”)
    urlRequest.addValue(“authkey”, forHTTPHeaderField: “Authorization”)
    urlRequest.addValue(“productid”, forHTTPHeaderField: “ProductId”)

    let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
    let task = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: urlRequest)
    task.resume()

}
```

I add all the necessary HTTP headers to the URLRequest and then try to establish a connection with the websocket. When the HTTP headers contain correct data it results in my application crashing with the stack trace exception "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)". If I intentionally alter the header data in order to be denied acccess then I'm just presented with a normal "Status Code: 403" when I try to connect.

Am I missing something crucial in my code? I assume the problem is related to the HTTP updgrade process, but I can't quite put my finger on the issue. Does it have anything to do with the configuration for URLSession? I'm thankful for any help I can get!

EDIT: Did some further digging and the server reports status 101 for the request, which means that I'm not handling the socket upgrade correctly in my code... Hmm

EDIT2: The exact same code is working fine in iOS 13, this issue seems to be related to WatchOS specifically. Will keep investigating and see if I can fix it somehow.

EDIT3: Tried Starscream now and it is working as long as I run the application on the simulator, it doesn't work on an actual Apple Watch though :( This is the output when I run the app on an Apple Watch:

```
2019-08-14 18:28:12.616649+0200 ______________ WatchKit Extension[279:27012] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C87] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2019-08-14 18:28:12.616784+0200 _______________ WatchKit Extension[279:27012] TCP Conn 0x14eadd00 Failed : error 0:50 [50]
websocket is disconnected: Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. Network is down")
```

Of course the actual WIFI network is not down on the Apple Watch. From what I gather this seems to be a quite common problem when going from simulator to physical device with certain libraries relying on network connections.

I've also started a ticket with Apple on their Feedback assistant service, I'm still waiting for a proper answer though. I've currently managed to narrow the problem down to the same conclusion as this post on the Apple forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/377041#377041

Will keep you updated!

Comment: You can check this tutorial https://ohmyswift.com/blog/2019/08/31/introducing-urlsessionwebsockettask-native-websocket-implementation-using-swift-5/ on how to implement native websockets in iOS13 using swift 5 @heinz_dieter

Answer (score 2):

Ok, at least I have an answer to my question now. After some back and forth with Apple through their Feedback-service this is their answer to my problem :

"Use of Networking APIs in process on the watch are limited so that user experience is not disrupted.

Current URLSessionWebSocketTask can only be used if an audio streaming session is currently activated. The developer can find more information here —

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/716/

Scrub to roughly 5 mins in the video where the speaker talks about using audio sessions.

We are also aware of the crash that the user is facing and even with the audio session active, the users will continue seeing this crash. We are tracking it under a different bug report."

So to sum it up, you need to start an audio session in order to use websockets in WatchOS. Starting an audio session prior to connecting the websocket still does not fix the current problem, but it seems like they are aware of that problem at least.

Hope that this can be of use to anyone trying to use websockets in WatchOS and let's hope that Apple gets around to fixing this before releasing WatchOS 6.

Final update: Apple released a new Xcode beta and also new WatchOs versions (6.1 beta and 6.0.1 stable) in the last couple of days. I can report that websockets seem to be working fine now! No need to start an audio session either before connecting the websocket. Happy days!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to use Starscream library? Does it work then? If yes then it smells like watchOS issue and please file a feedback (radar previously) so Apple could fix it before releasing watchOS officially.

Comment: Tried Starscream, seems to be working in the simulator, but not on a physical device :( See EDIT3 for more information.